# Can the following problem be cast as a geometric program?

Tags: geometric-programming

Consider the function $f : [0,1]^n \to [0,\infty)$ defined as
$$
f(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \sum_{(z_1,\dots,z_n) \in \{0,1\}^n} g(z_1,\dots,z_n) \cdot \left[\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{z_i} \cdot (1-x_i)^{1-z_i}\right]
$$
where $g(z_1,\dots,z_n) \geq 0$ for every $(z_1,\dots,z_n) \in \{0,1\}^n$. Note that the summation consists of $2^n$ terms. My objective is to solve the following problem:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    \min_{x_1,\dots,x_n}
    \quad & f(x_1,\dots,x_n), \\
    \textrm{s.t.} \quad & (x_1,\dots,x_n) \in \{y \in \mathbb R^n \mid y_1 \in [a_{1},1],\dots,y_n \in [a_{n},1]\}
    \end{aligned} \tag{1} \label{prob}
\end{equation}
where $0 \leq a_i < 1$ for each $i$. In other words, the decision variables $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are constrained to be within an $n$-dimensional hyperrectangle that is a subset of an $n$-dimensional hypercube. To solve the problem in \eqref{prob}, my strategy was to convert it into the standard form for a geometric program and then pass it to a solver. However, the main difficulty in doing so is that the literature that I have found on geometric programming constrain $g(z_1,\dots,z_n)$ to be strictly positive for every $(z_1,\dots,z_n) \in \{0,1\}^n$, while in my case, it can be $0$ for some $(z_1,\dots,z_n) \in \{0,1\}^n$. Therefore, $f$ is not strictly a posynomial. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

---

**Update**

Based on the definitions given [here](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Eee127/sp21/livebook/l_gp_posy.html), it seems that this isn't really a problem, as the summation in $f$ can be split as
\begin{align}
f(x_1,\dots,x_n) &= \sum_{\substack{(z_1,\dots,z_n) \in \{0,1\}^n \\ g(z_1,\dots,z_n) \neq 0}} g(z_1,\dots,z_n) \cdot \left[\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{z_i} \cdot (1-x_i)^{1-z_i}\right] \\
&+ \sum_{\substack{(z_1,\dots,z_n) \in \{0,1\}^n \\ g(z_1,\dots,z_n) = 0}} g(z_1,\dots,z_n) \cdot \left[\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{z_i} \cdot (1-x_i)^{1-z_i}\right] \\
&= \sum_{\substack{(z_1,\dots,z_n) \in \{0,1\}^n \\ g(z_1,\dots,z_n) \neq 0}} g(z_1,\dots,z_n) \cdot \left[\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{z_i} \cdot (1-x_i)^{1-z_i}\right]
\end{align}
However, I wonder if there is a better way to approach this problem in the first place, so I'm keeping this question open.

Comment: How is this any kind of generalized geometric program? Aside from being nonnegative, Your $g(x_1,...,x_n)$ could be anything. With such a general $g$, this is not necessarily transformable into a convex optimization problem. In the link you provide, the  $c_k$ are constants, not functions of the optimization variables - that is a crucial and "deal-breaking" difference.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Note that I wrote "$g(z_1,\dots,z_n)$" and not "$g(x_1,\dots,x_n)$" when defining $f$. $g$ is not a function of the decision variables $x_1,\dots,x_n$.

Comment: I misread $z_i$ as $x_o$. There's no problem if some g = 0, because that's the same as the term not being in the sum. So the objective is a  posynomial and the problem is a geometric program.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone thanks a lot for confirming this. This is unrelated to my main question, but I'm not sure how to show that the term $$\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{z_i} \cdot (1-x_i)^{1-z_i}$$ in the summation above is a monomial in $x_1,\dots,x_n$. Any suggestions?

Comment: A variable raised to a power is a monomial.  A product of monomials is a monomial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no problem if some $g(z_1,...,z_n) = 0$, because that's the same as the terms which have a zero $g(z_1,...,z_n)$ not being in the sum (objective function). So the objective is a posynomial, and the optimization problem is a geometric program.

The objective function is a posynomial because it is the sum of monomials. Each term in the sum is a monomial because a variable raised to a power is a monomial, and a product of monomials is a monomial.

Answer (score 2):

Just want to add some clarifications to @MarkL.Stone's answer. The function $$g(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{z_i} \cdot (1-x_i)^{1-z_i} \tag{1}$$ is **not** a monomial in $x_1,\dots,x_n$. The reason is that, according to section 1.2 in the paper *[Disciplined Geometric Programming](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/dgp.html)* (2019) by A. Agrawal, S. Diamond, and S. Boyd,

> A function is log-log affine if and only if it is a monomial

That is (see section 2.1 in the same paper), a function $f : D \to \mathbb R_+$, where $\mathbb R_+$ is the set of positive reals and $D \subseteq \mathbb R^n_+$, is a monomial if
$$
\forall x_1,x_2 \in D, \forall t \in [0,1], f\left(x_1^t \circ x_2^{1-t}\right) = f(x_1)^t \cdot f(x_2)^{1-t}
$$
where $\circ$ denotes elementwise product and $x^t = (x_1^t,\dots,x_n^t)$ denotes elementwise exponentiation. In the case of $(1)$, we have
\begin{align}
g(x_1)^t &= \prod_{i=1}^n x_{1i}^{tz_i} \cdot (1-x_{1i})^{t(1-z_i)} \\
g(x_2)^{1-t} &= \prod_{i=1}^n x_{2i}^{(1-t)z_i} \cdot (1-x_{2i})^{(1-t)(1-z_i)} \\
g(x_1)^t \cdot g(x_2)^{1-t} &= \prod_{i=1}^n x_{1i}^{tz_i} \cdot x_{2i}^{(1-t)z_i} \cdot (1-x_{1i})^{t(1-z_i)} \cdot (1-x_{2i})^{(1-t)(1-z_i)} 
\end{align}
but
\begin{align}
g\left(x_1^t \circ x_2^{1-t}\right) &= \prod_{i=1}^n (x_{1i}^t \cdot x_{2i}^{1-t})^{z_i} \cdot (1-(x_{1i}^t \cdot x_{2i}^{1-t}))^{1-z_i} \\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n x_{1i}^{tz_i} \cdot x_{2i}^{(1-t)z_i} \cdot (1-(x_{1i}^t \cdot x_{2i}^{1-t}))^{1-z_i} \\
&\neq g(x_1)^t \cdot g(x_2)^{1-t}
\end{align}
**However**, if we introduce the variable $y_i = 1 - x_i$ for each $i = 1,\dots,n$ with the equality constraint $x_i + y_i = 1$ for each $i$, then the following function is a monomial in $(x,y)$:
$$
h(x,y) = \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{z_i} \cdot y_i^{1-z_i} \tag{2}
$$
We can check if $h(x,y)$ is a monomial in $(x,y)$ using the same definition above:
\begin{align}
h(x_1,y_1)^t &= \prod_{i=1}^n x_{1i}^{tz_i} \cdot y_{1i}^{t(1-z_i)} \\
h(x_2,y_2)^{1-t} &= \prod_{i=1}^n x_{2i}^{(1-t)z_i} \cdot y_{2i}^{(1-t)(1-z_i)} \\
h(x_1,y_1)^t \cdot h(x_2,y_2)^{1-t} &= \prod_{i=1}^n x_{1i}^{tz_i} \cdot x_{2i}^{(1-t)z_i} \cdot y_{1i}^{t(1-z_i)} \cdot y_{2i}^{(1-t)(1-z_i)} 
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
h\left(x_1^t \circ x_2^{1-t},y_1^t \circ y_2^{1-t}\right) &= \prod_{i=1}^n x_{1i}^{tz_i} \cdot x_{2i}^{(1-t)z_i} \cdot y_{1i}^{(1-z_i)t} \cdot y_{2i}^{(1-t)(1-z_i)} \\
&= h(x_1,y_1)^t \cdot h(x_2,y_2)^{1-t}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. I did take a liberty as you have described with $(1-x_i)$.